# Stop empty ConstraintLayout from maximum stretching

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

When I remove all views from my Constraint layout, I want it to have 0dp height(like wrap_content as it sounds) but it stretches as much as possible.

Is there documented way to do that? I mean besides setting maxHeight to `0` or hiding it.

I've tried `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` with `"wrap_content"` but it doesnt work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find a proper solution.

---

The simplest workaround I came up with is to add an extra view with `height=0` and never remove it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/somethingWithNoHeight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

        <!--<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum" />-->
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I believe you should fill a bug to be sure that developers know about such a problem

Comment: I also went that way though I see here two inconveniences: a) indexes. you need to keep that in mind as every child index is incremented and it can lead to not that obvious bugs; b) constraints. again you can forget about that view and loose bunch of time playing with constraints in code not understanding why they behave that way

Comment: Maybe the better way is to extend a ConstarintLayout and override `onViewAdded` and `onViewRemoved` to set `visibility=View.GONE` itself if it has 0 children? Since you are using ConstarintLayout as root view, constraints on GONE views still should work